# Azure creating VM on existing VNET with multiple subnets

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have multiple VMs already in the same VNET. When I create a new VM trying to use that same VNET I get an error. I do not want to delete existing subnets (4) already in the vnet. All I want to do is add a new vm to the already existing vnet with a new subnet attached to it. I have seen similar posts but none show how to deal with multiple existing subnets.

This is the error

```
Subnet Foo2Subnet is in use by /subscriptions/<subid>/resourceGroups/foo-westus2/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/Foo2VMNic/ipConfigurations/Foo2 
 cannot be deleted. In order to delete the subnet, delete all the resources within the subnet. See aka.ms/deletesubnet.
```

here is how I am creating a new vm.

```
'az vm create ' \
    '--resource-group {resourceGroupName} ' \
    '--name  "{serverName}" ' \
    '--image "UbuntuLTS" ' \
    '--use-unmanaged-disk ' \
    '--vnet-name foo2VNET ' \
    '--subnet test1' \
    '--public-ip-address "" ' \
    '--storage-sku Standard_LRS ' \
    '--admin-username {user_name} ' \
    '--admin-password "{password}" ' \
    '--size "{vm_size}" ' \
    '--custom-data  "" --no-wait'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening - `az vm create` is attempting to perform a create vnet with this subnet only (so overwrite your existing vnet configuration). Nothing you can really do about this, what you can do is [precreate the subnet in the vnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/vnet/subnet?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-vnet-subnet-create), after that your command will work.

Comment: When I try that using cli 
`az network vnet subnet create -g {resourceGroupName} --vnet-name {vnet} -n {subnet_name} --address-prefixes 10.0.0.0/24'` 

I get  `Subnet '<subnet>' is not valid in virtual network '<vnet>'.`

Comment: Yep, that was the issue.